# Is there a chess software that allows to generate and store engine evaluation graph for a chess game?

Tags: analysis, software

A software like Fritz or Arena typically shows a graph for a game that is currently being analyzed/played. Fritz 5.32 also generates those graphs as it does automated analysis of several games in DB. But I want to keep those graphs available after I close a window, so that each game has a graph associated with it that I can easily retrieve. These are now getting available for live broadcasts like this one http://superfinal2012.live.whychess.com/, but I now want to do the same with my own games...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of recent versions of Fritz, I quote the following from the Fritz 12 Quick Guide:

> If you perform a ‘Blunder Check’ on a game and store the ‘Evaluation’,
>   then that will be used to populate the‘Evaluation Profile’ window
>   whenever you open that game from the database.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that SCID does this - 
http://www.chess.com/forum/view/chess-equipment/gui-to-make-analysis-graph